# Facing [io.undertow.request.io] (default task-4) Exception handling request to /business-central/: java.io.IOException: UT010029: Stream is closed

Tags: jboss, wildfly, jbpm, drools-kie-server, kie-server

I am working on jbpm-server-7.74.1.Final-dist project.
The jbpm workbench successfully authenticates and move to dashboard when the url is
http://localhost:8080/business-central/kie-wb.jsp

When I bind the IP address using is authenticating successfull as per the log but I'm getting the following error

14:41:56,839 DEBUG [org.kie.server.controller.impl.KieServerControllerImpl] (Thread-125) Server id sample-server known to the controller, checking if given server exists

14:41:56,840 DEBUG [org.kie.server.controller.impl.KieServerHealthCheckControllerImpl] (Thread-125) ping isAlive to location http://10.80.240.111:8080/kie-server/services/rest/server: connected.

14:41:58,198 DEBUG [io.undertow.request] (default I/O-11) Matched prefix path /business-central for path /business-central/j_security_check

14:41:58,200 DEBUG [io.undertow.request.security] (default task-4) Security constraints for request /business-central/j_security_check are [SingleConstraintMatch{emptyRoleSemantic=PERMIT, requiredRoles=[]}]

14:41:58,204 DEBUG [io.undertow.request.security] (default task-4) Setting authentication required for exchange HttpServerExchange{ POST /business-central/j_security_check}

14:41:58,205 DEBUG [org.wildfly.security.http.password] (default task-4) Username authentication. Realm: [null], Username: [wbadmin].

14:41:58,215 DEBUG [io.undertow.session] (default task-4) Created session with id o5L6Z0IuXJjX3SMj-3o2Ge4FgwQBvcJBBLMcknyQ for exchange HttpServerExchange{ POST /business-central/j_security_check}

14:41:58,217 DEBUG [io.undertow.session] (default task-4) Changing session id o5L6Z0IuXJjX3SMj-3o2Ge4FgwQBvcJBBLMcknyQ to 9ejKIT2_UIR24aYqyB2aQ-r1Ncezot8slvdZSq3n

14:41:58,218 DEBUG [org.wildfly.security.http.form] (default task-4) User [wbadmin] authenticated successfully

14:41:58,230 DEBUG [io.undertow.request.security] (default task-4) Authenticated as wbadmin, roles [admin, rest-all, kie-server]

14:41:58,250 DEBUG [io.undertow.request] (default I/O-11) Matched prefix path /business-central for path /business-central/

14:41:58,252 DEBUG [io.undertow.request.security] (default task-4) Security constraints for request /business-central/ are [SingleConstraintMatch{emptyRoleSemantic=PERMIT, requiredRoles=[]}]

14:41:58,254 DEBUG [org.apache.jasper.servlet] (default task-4) JspEngine --> /index.jsp

14:41:58,254 DEBUG [org.apache.jasper.servlet] (default task-4)              ServletPath: /index.jsp

14:41:58,255 DEBUG [org.apache.jasper.servlet] (default task-4)                 PathInfo: null

14:41:58,255 DEBUG [org.apache.jasper.servlet] (default task-4)                 RealPath: C:\Users\21335\Downloads\JBPMFinal\PostgreSQL\MYSQLJBPMWithPropertiesStore\jbpm-server-7.74.1.Final-dist\standalone\tmp\vfs\temp\tempb5da42ee686ced0b\content-9f3ef3f294bb1cd8\index.jsp

14:41:58,256 DEBUG [org.apache.jasper.servlet] (default task-4)               RequestURI: /business-central/

14:41:58,256 DEBUG [org.apache.jasper.servlet] (default task-4)              QueryString: null

14:41:58,257 DEBUG [io.undertow.session] (default task-4) Created session with id TGnCbFxr8COsZZFAJuoE8NtBZOgEWbakYbVLQfxc for exchange HttpServerExchange{ GET /business-central/}

14:41:58,259 DEBUG [io.undertow.request.io] (default task-4) Exception handling request to /business-central/: java.io.IOException: UT010029: Stream is closed
at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.5.Final//io.undertow.servlet.spec.ServletOutputStreamImpl.write(ServletOutputStreamImpl.java:138)

please help me should I change any configurations of wildfly server.